# Make a pandas dataframe using one available series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series for players as follows:

```
0 1
1 1
2 3
3 4
```

My expected output is:

```
    players   teams   night   morning
0      1       []     []        []
1      1       []     []        []
2      3       []     []        []
3      4       []     []        []
```

This is what I have tried:

```
players_ids = players_ids()
df = pd.DataFrame({'players': players_ids, 'teams': None, 'night': None, 'morning': None})
```

But what I get is this:

```
    players   teams    night       morning
0      1       None     None        None
1      1       None     None        None
2      3       None     None        None
3      4       None     None        None
```

but this just shows `None` rather than `[]`. Is there any easy solution in pandas for this?

Comment: Why would you want empty lists (or lists to fill)? They'd be of type `object` and you might as well just use nested lists

Comment: for further usage I needed to add some values to it and then make some calculations. You mean totally skip the pandas?

Comment: Well, pandas gives you nothing here unless you can think of a way to get scalar values into the DataFrame

Comment: I have solution with pure python, but just wanted to know how does it work with pandas as my datas may rich to nGigabyte

Comment: I don't know what those fields are even supposed to represent but it seems you could have individual rows rather than aggregating into lists. You might _think_ that it's quicker if you aggregate things into lists, but you'd be wrong (if that is indeed your logic)

Comment: How may I refer values to a specific player without list. Could you please give provide me an example and post it as answer or give me a link?

Comment: No, because I don't know what you even intend to use the lists for. You'll have to look into `.loc` and `.groupby` I guess but... I'm not guessing your use-case for you

Comment: Thanks, I guess got your point. I'll try to avoid aggregate things into lists, rather use `groupby`. Something like assigning values to a sql database table, right?

Comment: It works very much like SQL if you use it correctly

Comment: Furthermore, `pandas` specifically uses `cython` to compile `groupby` down to C++, so it's a very efficient operation

Comment: Great now everything is clear to me. I hope you could give this explanations as answer that I could accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose eludes me, but this can be done by filling the `None` values with empty lists:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'players': [1, 1, 3, 4], 'teams': None, 'night': None, 'morning': None})
df = df.applymap(lambda x: [] if not x else x)
```

Result:

```
    players teams   night   morning
0   1       []      []      []
1   1       []      []      []
2   3       []      []      []
3   4       []      []      []
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution is the correct answer for my question however my approach to add lists and aggravating the values is a bit inefficient.